# How yo make 3 types user in different table but they have all a email, password, username?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design

I'm planning to develop a system with three types of users (admin, business, personal). I would like to store each user's information in a separate table for data variance. All three have a username, password, and email. How to make that?

Comment: If you're going to use Laravel, it works best with a single `users` table with either a `role` column (allows each User to have a single Role like `admin`, `business` OR `personal)`, or a `roles` table with a pivot table `role_user` to link them (allows each User to have one OR many roles, like `admin` and `business`, `admin` and `personal`, just `admin`, etc.) You'll need to choose the approach that best works for you, but having a table for each user is probably the worst way to go, as it doesn't function with Laravel's Models and Relationships (speaking from experience on that)

Comment: `Do you have a link explaining what you say and how it works`...is there something specific you didn't understand in what I said?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to store each user's information in a separate table

...no, that's a bad idea. Don't de-normalise your schema like that, it will cause you lots of problems.

Instead, just have another column in the users table called "role" which indicates what kind of user they are.

If you need other fields which are only useful to certain types of user, then either

a) put them in the users table as optional fields, or

b) create separate role-based tables with a 1-1 relationship to the main table.

(IMHO the first option is more flexible and requires less maintenance.)